# How do you clone scripts into Tools on Roblox?

Tags: lua, roblox

So I have tried to code a script which will clone a script (Clicks) into every item in the folder (Tools), in ServerStorage. This doesn't work however and I need some help. Can anyone please help me out?

```
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local ServerStorage = game:GetService("ServerStorage")

local remotes = ReplicatedStorage:FindFirstChild("Remotes")
local tools = ServerStorage:FindFirstChild("Tools") --Tools is a folder in ServerStorage 
local scripts = ServerStorage:FindFirstChild("Scripts") --Scripts is a folder in ServerStorage

remotes.ToolActivated.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player: player) --Dw about this its for my game
    print(player.name)
end)


for _, tool in ipairs(tools:GetChildren()) do --Main part of where I tried to clone the script (Clicks)
    local script = script.Click:Clone()
    script.Parent = tool
end
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the Output widget?

Comment: No, i dont its all good at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Try validating that there is a `Click` script within the script that is being executed.

```lua
local clickScript = script:WaitForChild("Click")
for _, tool in pairs(tools:GetChildren()) do
    if typeof(clickScript) ~= 'Instance' then
        break
    end
    local clone = select(2, pcall(game.Clone, clickScript))
    if typeof(clone) == 'Instance' then
        clone.Parent = tool
    end
end
```